# New script: Questions needing attention

Tags: discussion

You have already scrolled the Questions page twice, and still looking for other questions to answer?
This script is made for you!

http://data.stackexchange.com/opendata/query/285084/questions-needing-attention

Press `Run Query` and you will get a list of questions that need to be upvoted/downvoted/answered.

Some questions slip through without getting proper attention... this script can help us do a better job at letting no question behind.

Reminder: Questions with zero votes (among other conditions) get deleted automatically by Roomba after some time, it would be a shame to loose good questions just because nobody bothered to upvote them.

*The data is updated [every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq). This is a limitation of StackExchange.*

Comment: For anyone interested: Here are the [current policies for removing old abandoned questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).